# In CoreVideo and CoreMedia for iOS apps, what determines the dimension of the video sample buffer?

Tags: uikit, core-video, core-media

I am building an iOS app (XCode 12.3, iPhone 12pro), and using the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` I run the `captureOutput` function which gives me a `sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer`. I inspect the dimensions using `CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer)` and it comes out to: `dimensions: 1504 x 1128`.

How are these dimensions determined? I'm simply confused because they don't seem to correspond to either the view size or any camera dimensions (like 720p or 1080p, see [specs](https://www.apple.com/iphone-12-pro/specs/)) I've seen documented. I have looked at Apple's [CoreMedia documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/CoreMedia) and could not find this information. I'm new to CoreMedia, so I might be missing something basic about how this framework is designed.

Comment: Did you ever end up finding the solution?

Comment: I have made no progress :)